# DJANGO > Renderizar um FOR dentro de outro

Tags: python, django, template

Estou com uma situação que é a seguinte:

Preciso fazer no html uma tablea onde tenho que mostrar os totalizadores e uma linha e os valores que compoem esse totalizador, como um pequeno exemplo abaixo

Receitas = 100.000,00

Salarios = 60.000,00

Extras    = 40.000,00

Porém não sei muito bem como seria fazer isso.

Abaixo tenho os models:
1º GrupoDre (seria os totalizadores)

```
class Grupodre(models.Model):
master_user = models.ForeignKey('accounts.User', models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Usuario Master')
num_grupodre = models.IntegerField('Código')
descricao = models.CharField('Nome Grupo', max_length=20)
ordem = models.PositiveIntegerField('Ordem no relatório')

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Grupo DRE'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Grupos DRE'
    unique_together = [
        ('master_user', 'num_grupodre')
    ]



def __str__(self):
    return str(self.descricao)
```

2º Plano Financeiro (seria referente a classificação dos lançamentos)

class PlanoFinan(models.Model):

```
Scategoria_Choices = (
    (None,'Informe o sinal'),
    ('D', 'Despesas'),
    ('R', 'Receitas'),
)


# informação do dono da conta (usuario Master)
master_user = models.ForeignKey('accounts.User',models.CASCADE,verbose_name='Usuario Master')
# dados principais
num_plfin = models.IntegerField('Código')
descricao = models.CharField('Descricão',max_length=60)
sinal = models.CharField('Sinal Conta',max_length=1,choices=Scategoria_Choices)
grupodre = models.ForeignKey('niluscad.Grupodre',models.SET_NULL,verbose_name='Grupo Dre',null=True,blank=True)


class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Plano Financeiro'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Plano Financeiro'
    unique_together = [
        ('master_user', 'num_plfin')
    ]


def __str__(self):
    return self.descricao
```

3º Lançamentos (model onde recebe os valores para totalizar)

```
Class Lancamentos(models.Model):
# informação do dono da conta (usuario Master)
master_user = models.ForeignKey('accounts.User',models.CASCADE,verbose_name='Usuario Master')

# dados principais (empresa e numero do lançamento)
num_lan = models.IntegerField('Nº Registro')
parcela = models.IntegerField('Parcela',default=1)
company = models.ForeignKey('niluscad.Company',models.CASCADE,verbose_name='Empresa')


#dados do titulo
cadgeral = models.ForeignKey('niluscad.CadGeral',models.CASCADE,verbose_name='Cliente',blank=True,null=True)
dt_lancamento = models.DateField('Data Lançamento',null=True,blank=True)
dt_vencimento = models.DateField('Data Vencimento',null=True,blank=True)
plr_financeiro = models.ForeignKey('niluscad.Planofinan',models.PROTECT,verbose_name='Plano Financeiro')
conta_finan = models.ForeignKey('nilusfin.Contafinanceira',models.PROTECT,verbose_name='Conta Recebimento')
c_custo = models.ForeignKey('niluscad.Ccusto',models.PROTECT,verbose_name='Centro de Custo')
vlr_lancamento = models.DecimalField('Valor do Lançamento',max_digits=13,decimal_places=2,blank=True,null=True)
valor_text = models.CharField(verbose_name='Valor',  max_length=20)
saldo = models.DecimalField('Saldo', max_digits=13,decimal_places=2,blank=True,null=True)
descricao = models.CharField(verbose_name='Observação', max_length=70,null=True,blank=True)
titulo = models.BooleanField('É Titulo', default=False)


#Dados Cotação/Indice
indice = models.ForeignKey('nilusfin.Indice',models.PROTECT,null=True,blank=True)
cotacao = models.ForeignKey('nilusfin.Cotacao',models.PROTECT,null=True,blank=True)



situacao = models.BooleanField('Baixado',default=False)
reaberto = models.BooleanField('Reaberto',default=False)
data_baixa = models.DateField('Data de Recebimento',null=True,blank=True)
lancamento_pai = models.ForeignKey('self',models.SET_NULL,blank=True,null=True,verbose_name='Lançamento Pai')

# Dados Baixa e Situação
tipoLancto_Choices = (
    ('R', 'Receita'),
    ('D', 'Despesa'),
)

tipo_lancamento = models.CharField('Tipo', max_length=1, choices=tipoLancto_Choices)


 class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Lançamento'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Lançamentos'
    unique_together = [
        ('master_user', 'num_lan','parcela')
    ]

def __str__(self):
     return str(int((self.pk)))
```

Gostaria como posso montar uma View para assim renderizar no template conforme exemplo acima.

Obrigado a todos pela atenção.

Answer (score 1):

Dê uma vista de olhos na documentação que ela consegue ser melhor do que as respostas nesta comunidade. Convém ler bem a documentação para compreender as raízes do Django.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/

Comment: Então meu amigo, já dei uma olhada, o problema é que a UPDATEVIEW pega um registro de acordo com o parametro da seleção dentro da URL.
o problema é que ele retorna, mas demora muito, queria ver se consigo um UPDATEVIEW onde o registro me retorne mais rápido.